# Use Rails API with ActiveStorage DirectUpload and Ember JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Rails guides [explain](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#integrating-with-libraries-or-frameworks) how to use ActiveStorage with other libraries. I wonder how a separate Ember App can figure out of existence of `DirectUpload` class from `activestorage` ?

Comment: It seems like the suggested implementation supposes your client app to be a part of a Raise app and is located somewhere in `Rails.root` hierarchy. If you use a separate front-end client, no matter React, Angular, Ember or whatever, you'll have to override [DirectUploadsController`](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-api/blob/add_file_upload/app/controllers/direct_uploads_controller.rb). and set up [host](https://github.com/belgoros/draft-api/blob/add_file_upload/config/environments/development.rb#L32) option in the corresponding environment file.